# Android new user tutorial

Tags: android, design-patterns

By in-app tutorial I mean [this](http://www.android-app-patterns.com/category/tutorials)

1. Do those in-app tutorials have special technical term to use, so it's possible to filter all those unrelated results?
2. How to implement them? Tried looking it up in Google, but obviously got keyword collision leading to unrelated results.

Comment: "android app onboarding" gives some useful results. Btw. extensive in-app tutorials are probably not a good idea, especially when they are mandatory.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Thanks. Now if you would put it up as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some useful results with the search terms "android app onboarding".

Btw. extensive in-app tutorials are probably not a good idea, especially when they are mandatory.